# Why can the code between ifndef/endif still get run here?

Tags: c++, syntax

```
#define cimg_use_jpeg 2

#ifndef cimg_use_jpeg

//code goes here

#endif
```

I really don't understand...

Comment: please show a complete piece of c demonstrating what you think is incorrect, because the code shouldn't even be compiled. try `gcc -E` to get preprocessor output

Comment: It can if there is an #undef after the #define. What is your exact code?

Comment: or if there is an #ifdef around the #define. or several 100s of other options. but it shouldn't be compiled as it stands here.

Comment: +1 for understanding the need to turn to SO when your mind is blocked so you cannot see the answer yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time things similar to this (so-called impossible things) happen me, the reason is: The code I see in my editor is not the code that runs. This can happen in many ways.

- forgetting to make
- forgetting to save
- saving a copy of the code
- running in a different evironment from the one you compiled to
- the new code ran but I opened and am looking at the old output

Comment: +1 When I'm debugging, I'll `#if 0 /* old code */ #else /* new code */ #endif` so I can try out the fix but be able to revert to the original easily.  I sometimes accidentally make changes in `/* old code */` thinking that I'm changing `/* new code */`, and then nothing changes when I recompile.

Comment: @cape1232 why not use source control? the whole purpose of source control is to allow you to revert, and it's often more manageable than your manual version control...

Comment: @atk I do it like cape1232 for changes I excpect only to last a couple of minutes. Then came the phone call ...

Comment: @atk I use both.  Like Peter G said, the `#if` is good for quick changes, without polluting your commit logs.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be executed. Maybe you run incorrect executable version. Printing `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` to trace or log helps to detect such errors.

Comment: `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` will display correctly if you surround them with backticks. I fixed that for you.

Answer (score 0):

This should definately work as you expect. The code in the `#ifndef/#endif` block will not even be compiled by the compiler, assuming the `cimg_use_jpeg` is defined as expected.

So the question is, is the `cimg_use_jpeg` defined as you expect? Or are you simplifying your question and by virtue of the simplification providing a sample that actually works?

Answer (score 0):

@Anders K.  This works, i.e. the proper things are not executed.  The code produces "BAZ is undefined"

```
#define FOO 2
#define BAR

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
#ifndef FOO
  std::cout << "FOO is undefined" << std::endl;
#endif

#ifndef BAR
  std::cout << "BAR is undefined" << std::endl;
#endif

#ifndef BAZ
  std::cout << "BAZ is undefined" << std::endl;
#endif
}
```

Comment: just because it works doesn't mean you should. it is confusing for the reader to know the point of the '2' if you are just looking to see if the symbol is defined (that was what I meant in my post)

Comment: Yep.  I should have changed the 2 to a 1.  That 2 is confusing.

Answer (score -1):

Either you write

```
#define yoursymbol

#ifdef yoursymbol
```

or you write

```
#define yoursymbol somevalue

#if yousymbol == somevalue
```

don't mix them

EDIT: 
since people seem to misunderstand what I meant here's a clarification: when you program it is important to code so that other people understand what your intentions are, so if your intention is only to check whether a symbol is defined it is confusing to specify a numerical value.

Comment: -1: Off topic, doesn't answer question. He does NOT want the code to execute.

Comment: You can mix them.  See my answer (because I can't put code in a comment).

Comment: @mathepic was just showing the principle, not off topic. Actually it isn't good style to mix. Either you want to use the value of the macro symbol or you just want to know whether the symbol itself is defined but by mixing you make it unclear for the reader what the intention is with the macro.

Comment: @cape1232 just because you can doesn't mean you should

Comment: True.  Especially since the symbol is defined as 2.  However, I like `#define FOO 1` and `#if FOO` better than `#define FOO` and `#ifdef FOO` because then I can toggle the code on and off by changing one character (`1` to `0`) rather than having to change `#define` to `#undef` (or worse deleting the line entirely).  Plus I find `#if FOO` easier on my eyes than `#ifdef FOO`.  This is all subjective, of course.  I do agree, though, that you should pick one or the other approach.